# Are clogs in the AC condensate drain common in Florida?

Tags: air-conditioning, central-air

I have a two year old central A/C unit.  Every 2/3 months the unit shuts off.

I called the rep/maintenance company and they have given me the following response:

- The cause of the issue is algae building up within the drainage line
- This is due to the climate in Florida
- This is extremely common, and in fact comprises the majority of their service calls

Their solution is to:

- Shop vac the drainage line
- Pour bleach down the line

I have asked co-workers, family members in state, and a friend who's father has been in A/C for a few decades in the south an no one else has heard of this / has this issue.

This was most definitely not explained during the purchase of the new unit.

Does anyone know if this normal?  Am I getting hosed?

Comment: I think the technical part of the question is within scope.

Answer (score 8):

I live in South Florida and I too have to do this. My house has 2 AC systems. One of them clogs up after about 3-4 months, the other never has. I'm not sure what the difference is, but ever since I started putting a bit of bleach in the condensate line every time I change my filters; I've had no clogs since then.

Assuming this is actually your problem, I would suggest that you do the same.

Comment: Seeings though you are in FL and have the same issue, and treat it with the proposed solution I think this is probably the best answer I am going to get.  Thanks.

Comment: +1, I put a little bleach in the condensate trap every year. The frequency varies by location, and if it's too frequent, you may be missing the source. The shop vac is the easiest way to clear a line once it becomes clogged.

Comment: I just moved from FL (central near Melbourne) and we had this issue too. A little bleach down the drain twice a year and we were good. The first time it was so bad we used an air compresser to blow it out. It was the drain line that runs outside that would clog.

Answer (score 3):

use of bleach over time will corrode your pvc line ;
- use distilled vinegar; probably white - it will not damage your line ; I work homeowner claims and see a dozen of these type claims every couple weeks; probably couple hundred a year from FL.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the shop vac, but I've heard the bleach suggestion numerous times and it sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I have never heard of it happening. But it's  entirely possible. I  woukd be wary of uding Bleach, ubless you dilute it a lot  And even then, you shouldn't do it often.

I would confirm  from them in writing tgat, bleach wont adversely affect the plastic. Then they will be responsible.

> **Is Bleach corrosive?**
> Yes, it is corrosive to plastic. It does not eat up the plastic in one go (we are assuming you are using the diluted bleach or bleach water as the cleaning agent), but the damage it would create is definite.
>
> If you’ll keep using this mixture on your plastic surfaces or continue using the bottle for long, you’ll see clear evidence of damage.

[Reference](https://allegianceclean.com/is-bleach-corrosive-to-plastic/)

Yes it comes in plastic bottles, but that plastic is thicker and more resistant to oxidation/reduction. From personal experience  it still eats through those bottles in a few years.

Answer (score 0):

bleach is the best and as mentioned above and it wont hurt plastic heck it comes in a thin plastic bottle also condensate pans are made of plastic too so nothing to corrode their either.....

Comment: This is not true. There is a reason the bleach comes in certain types of plastic bottle. This is a dangerous suggestion. [Read](https://allegianceclean.com/is-bleach-corrosive-to-plastic/)